# Swagger Bearer token only works in one controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have created a web api using .net core. I used JWT for the authentication and was able to create users in my user controller using the authorization attribute. However the authorization attribute does not seem to work in any other controller except this one. Am I missing a step or something?

programs.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DisplayNameAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.DisplayName ?? x.Name);
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
         {
               new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                 {
                     Reference = new OpenApiReference
                     {
                         Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                         Id = "Bearer"
                     }
                 },
                 new string[] {}
         }
     });
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["JwtAuth:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = configuration["JwtAuth:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtAuth:Key"]))
                };
            });
```

user controller.cs

```
[HttpPost()]
[ActionName("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> login([FromBody] User_login login)
{
   User_login _Login = new();
    
   response _response = await _Login.login(login,configuration);
    
   return new ObjectResult(_response) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK };
}
    
[HttpPost()]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[ActionName("create-user")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<IActionResult> createUser([FromBody] createClient client)
{
   createClient _createClient = new();
    
   response _response = await _createClient.saveClientInformation(client);
    
   return new ObjectResult(_response) { StatusCode= StatusCodes.Status201Created};

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which controller it is working and which controller it is not? And attributes on different controllers.

Comment: Do you mean when other controller add `[Authorize]` attribute, They don't work? Just the controller you provide can work?